# Project Organization, searchable keywords and tags in Adobe Premiere

Tags: video, premiere, editing, final-cut-pro-x

In Final Cut Pro X you are able to add "tags" or "keywords" as a form of labeling clips. This way when you are editing you can search to bring up all the clips relating to those tags or keywords.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
Example:
Name --- Tags
Clip1: profile, interview
Clip2: audio, interview
Clip3: B-roll
Clip4: B-roll

Search = "interview"
Results = Clip1, Clip2
//////////////////////////////////////////
```

Adobe Premiere uses "bins" "metadata" and "labels" to organize media. Labels however are limited to about 6 I believe. Sure you can create a bunch of bins and copy and paste clips to use bins like keywords in a sense, however one of the great features of editing software is that clips show which parts of them are used in a sequence, when you copy and paste clips in the project panel you now have two separate entities, so if you where to use one and not the other, even though they are the same clip premiere will only show the one you used was used in a sequence. (Which kinda defeats the purpose).

How do you use keywords and or tags just like you can in Final Cut Pro X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keywords are an optional field of the project panel. In order to view or add keywords, you need to set the project panel to *List View* (you can switch between *List View* and *Icon View* with the buttons in the lower left corner).

In the flyout menu of the project panel, select *Metadata Display…* to customize the columns of the list view to show whatever information you want it to. You will find the keywords in the category *Dublin Core*. Check keywords and click ok. You might have to resize the project panel (or remove the columns you don't need from the Metadata Display menu) in order to see the keyword column. You can rearrange the columns using drag-and-drop. Once you have added some tags to your clips, you can search for clips with specific tags using the search function of the project panel.

There's also some more useful metadata columns hidden in that menu that are not shown by default that you might find useful. For example, the category *Premiere Pro Project Metadata* has the entries *Video Usage* and *Audio Usage* that show you how many instances of a clip exist in your sequences in your current project. There are also fields for *Comment*, *Description*, *Scene*, *Shot* and much more. Using the Metadata Display menu, you can customize the metadata columns to only show those that you need for your workflow.

[image: project panel]

Comment: I scoured the internet and never found this, I don't understand why it isn't more publicized. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Rext You're welcome :) Yeah, some functions are hidden pretty well ... in general, the cool stuff is hidden behind the flyout menu (the little burger menu icon next to the panel name). Whenever I forget how to get to a specific submenu or setting, it's usually in one of the flyout menues ...

Comment: I've found keywords and entered a few, I have two questions. One I used comma as a separator and I think it auto changed to a semicolon so I'm assuming the separator is a semicolon. Second, When I type in the search field it doesn't seem to pull up any of the keywords I've used.

Comment: Is there search option for the bar at the top? It seems that the search icon at the bottom that allows you to search using certain parameters is necessary to be able to search for keywords. Otherwise the search bar at the top doesn't even look for keywords.

Comment: @Rext I'm not sure as I don't usually use keywords ... the mouseovertext says 'an unordered array of descriptive phrases or keywords', so I would assume you can just seperate keywords with a blank space? What version of Premiere are you using? With the current version of Premiere CC that I have installed, both the search bar at the top as well as the search function at the bottom find all the keywords I have added, regardless of what I used as a seperator ...

Comment: I use premiere pro CC 2015, the separator is ; I learned. The search function at the bottom works but you have to specify two search criteria. The search box doesn't seem to search any metadata.

Comment: @Rext well that is inconvenient ... but with the current version that doesn't seem to case. Maybe you can update your version? Shouldn't be a problem if you have CC anyway ...

Comment: yeah haha seems like it. I'll look into it, thanks again!